# How to get changed hidden value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I made a darkmode function that changes the background color and text color of my application. It works well, but the thing is when I go to other page on value="dark", the value attribute is reset, new page is in value="light". I have to send dark mode value to other page. How do I do that?

Javascript file

```js
function Darkmode(self){ 
    if($('#dm').val() === 'light'){
        Color.backgroundColor('DarkSlateGray');
        Color.textColor('white');
           $('#dm').val('dark');
    } else {
        Color.backgroundColor('white');
        Color.textColor('black');
           $('#dm').val('light');
    }
}
```

part of the base.blade.php  tag:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="dm" name="darkmode" value="">
</head>
```

index.blade.php file that calls the Darkmode function:

```html
<button style="margin: 19px;" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="Darkmode(this);">
Darkmode
</button>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, if you want it to be persistent, you need to actually store the value somewhere. If you update a page or go to another page, everything you did on the first page without saving the value somehow (php session, cookie, local storage etc), it won't exist anymore. Values in forms aren't automatically stored some place. If you want to store it, you need to handle that in your code.

Comment: you can use a $_GET variable in url to pass your value something like  https://yoursite.com?dm=dark , otherwise you have to to made a form and submit it to pass the value in PHP $_POST

Comment: @Sim1-81 Could you explain it with code? then Do I have to pass URL parameter like `<form action="{{ route('events.index') }}">
        <input style="margin: 19px;" class="btn btn-dark" name="mode" value="light" type="submit" onclick="
            Darkmode(this);
</form>`
and change `function Darkmode(self){  
    if( $_GET['mode'] === 'light'){ 
//      Color.backgroundColor('DarkSlateGray');
        Color.textColor('white');
//and how to set "mode=dark" here?
});`

Comment: i've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using localstorage

```
function Darkmode(self){ 
    const mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
    if(mode) {      
        if(mode === 'light') {
            Color.backgroundColor('DarkSlateGray');
            Color.textColor('white');           
            localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
        }
        else {
            Color.backgroundColor('white');
            Color.textColor('black');
            localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
        }
    }

    // default if no setting saved
    else {
        Color.backgroundColor('white');
        Color.textColor('black');
        localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");  
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and not worked. but after I attached below code, it works. For me, It looks same with your code. do you have any idea why is this happen?
`function sm(mode) {
    if(mode === 'dark') {
        Color.backgroundColor('DarkSlateGray');
        Color.textColor('white');
    }
    else {
        Color.backgroundColor('white');
        Color.textColor('black');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
    if(mode){
        sm(mode);
    } else{
        localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
        sm('light');
    }
});`

Comment: I think that's because the function doesn't get called at start, in the `$(document).ready()` such that a mode aint selected and colors arent set? Untill you actually do select one, the code you attached code would resolve that. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you refresh the page the value / state is gone, what you code do is to save the value in your global javascript [store](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage) like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('mode','dark');
```

And get it like this:

```
var currentMode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
```

And check that state on every page load.

You could also save that value to your database and query which mode the user is entering, I would create a separate column in the users table and update the state for the individual user there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Darkmode()` function is working well, but it is only working in your current page as JS will be re-rendered every time you redirect to a new page or refresh the page.

If you want the value to be persistent, you may store it in **local storage** or pass it as **URL parameters**. Then you could get the value in each page's initialization

Comment: Could you explain URL parameter with code? I made this code on view page <form action="{{ route('events.index') }}"> <input style="margin: 19px;" class="btn btn-dark" name="mode" value="light" type="submit" onclick=" Darkmode(this); "> {{-- or like this?! <button style="margin: 19px;" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="mode" onclick=" Darkmode(this); ">Darkmode</button> --}} </form> and what should JS file be like?

Answer (score 0):

to add the get variables in URL your form action should be something like this

```
<form id="myForm" action="{{ route('events.index') }}?mode=dark"> <input style="margin: 19px;" class="btn btn-dark" name="mode" value="dark" type="submit" > </form>
```

via javascript you can retrieve them by this code :

```
function getGetVariables(){
    var get_variables = new Object(); 
    get_variables = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) { get_variables[key] = value; }); 
    console.log(get_variables);

     return get_variables;
}
```

in this way you have a PHP $_GET array substitute in a javascript object. 
But everytimes you reload the page you have to check get_variables.mode value. 
To make the script works the trick is trigger Darkmode function at the document ready in every pages

so your Darkmode function becomes

```
function Darkmode(){ 
    var urlVars = getGetVariables();
    var formUrl = document.getElementById("myForm").action.split('?');
    if(urlVars.mode === 'light'){
        /* do something */

       document.getElementById("myForm").action = formUrl[0] + '?mode=dark';
    } else if(urlVars.mode === 'dark') { 
        /* do something else */
       document.getElementById("myForm").action = formUrl[0] + '?mode=light;
    }
}
```

via javascript you can trigger the darkmode function in this way

```
window.onload="Darkmode()";
```

or using HTML on body onload in this way

```
<body onload="Darkmode()">
```

think also to introduce a default value in case ?mode= is not defined

But Such as Jelle Bruisten and Utdev have suggested, use the browser localstorage is a good way to do the same thing keeping pretty urls for SEO